# Filter on many to many table django

Tags: python, django

I have the following show table in Django. What I want is that I have a filter on ShowInfo which gives me 4 result. Now I want related shows of all 4 shows without a for loop.  Because for loop gives me duplicated values. I want to get related shows of all filtered show distinct without a loop.

```
class ShowInfo(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    related_shows = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True, related_name='all_related_shows', symmetrical=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with a specific show, you can do this:

```
s = ShowInfo.objects.get(pk=id) #assuming id is the id of a specific show
s.related_shows.all() #This will return all shows without duplicates.
```

Now, if you want just 4 results:

```
s.related_shows.all()[:4]
```

To iterate on this related_show you can:

```
for r in s.related_shows.all():
    r.related_shows.all()
```

It will not give you duplicated results. But, if you want results that are not duplicated in your whole set, you can use set:

```
all_results = []
for r in s.related_shows.all():
    all_results.append(show for r.related_shows.all())

set(all_Results) #This will show you a set with all_shows without duplicates
```

Here is some info about Many-to-many relationships: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: just change in code s = ShowInfo.objects.filter() returns 4 result and i want collective related show for 4 results. Not from a for loop